# IIS virtual directory page can’t be found myip/ccb/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fccb%2FHome%2FIndex

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-core

I created virtual directory for asp.net core app.

alias /ccb/

I have following method fol authorization:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize(string token)
        {
            try
            {
                token = token.Replace(" ", "+");
                string tokenString = _manager.Decrypt(token.ToString());
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(tokenString);
                var userName = json.userName.ToString();

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, "Qwerty123!", false, false);                
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }       
.............................................
```

I run application 
**myip/ccb/Account/Authorize?token=ydabAoMygbaOJg9tfcsulWwtM0wyqNnzEkbxBgxYEr0eHyMiOExQ29uikor2hPTyMT1/6oy7q2wexC/PpZ/TruPjT/NZDBAg81ZzHpCC40gkj4nvGpB2+lU5KO8qnhLCNXEwPI7z9hwESj1RdvfsESuC5iS8rz26F6SuXvKV0es=**

but get error:

No web page was found for the web address: **http://myip:8003/ccb/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fccb%2FHome%2FIndex**

If I running app local with visual studio everything fine.

Why this error. Help please. Thank you

Comment: in IIS, it should be **application** not **virtual directory**

Comment: yes. i used convert to application